# Como puedo agrupar varios productos en una sola consulta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy tratando de unir varios productos en una sola consulta y obtengo el resultado, pero deseo que el resultado me lo muestre separado por filas y que no se muestre separado por comas ni por puntos, por favor me podrian ayudar.

La consulta que actualmente estoy usando es:

```
SELECT fecha_registro,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_productos SEPARATOR '\n') 
FROM `wp_codificador_ventas` 
WHERE SUBSTR(wp_codificador_ventas.fecha_registro,1,10)>='2023-01-01'
AND SUBSTR(wp_codificador_ventas.fecha_registro,1,10)<='2023-02-10' 
GROUP BY usuario,cups,id_accion;
```

pero como lo comento deseo es que separar el resultado por filas

Comment: Prueba quitar el `group_concat`, así: `SELECT fecha_registro, id_productos FROM ...`

Comment: otra alternativa es `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_productos SEPARATOR '\n')  as detalle`